# add the current date to a pdf (when opened in browser)

Tags: javascript, pdf, sharepoint

I currently have a javaScript in a pdf that adds the current date once the document is opened in adobe.

```
function dateToday()
{
var date = new Date();
field = this.getField("todayDate");
field.value = date;
}
dateToday();
```

Now I want to upload this documents on a Sharepoint. But logically when I open the docs in the browser the javaScript is not triggered and the date is not updated (also when printing).

Is there any way I can change the script so it triggers when the pdf is opened in a browser?
Or how can I change the script so that it instead prints an error message when downloaded and opened in Adobe?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

We use [Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint](https://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint.aspx) On-Open functionality to add Dynamic Content(Current Date, User name, etc). You can find more details at https://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/04/applying-user-specific-watermarks-when.html

They also provide various watermarking facilities for details see http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/23730002-What-are-the-watermarking-facilities-of-the-PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint-